# VBA to Clear Template not Deleting Everything?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote a macro to clear the data of an excel template I use every day.  I put copied images and text into the template, save it and then the next day use the macro to clear it and repeat the process.  I've noticed after a month or two the file has become extremely large for what it contains.  It was about 50KB and is now 18,317KB with about the same amount of data.  The increase was gradual, not immediate.  Probably a few hundred KB a day.

I've checked to see if there is any formatting in the cells and there isn't.  I think my code deletes all of the cells in each sheet except for the last (which contains very little data), but I'm not sure if it is working.

```
Sub Reset_Template()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    Cells.AutoFilter
    End If
    Sheets(I).Select
    ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Select
    Selection.Delete
    Cells.Select
    Range("C67").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Cells.Select

    Next I

    Sheets(1).Select
    Cells.Select    
End Sub
```

Is my macro somehow not deleting all of the contents of my template? Or could it be something to do with the spreadsheet's settings?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it not be easier to save the template as a 'Read Only' file so that you don't save over it each day but instead save a copy of it with the copied images/text, then whenever you re-enter the spreadsheet you will not need to reset it as it will be in the same state as you left it?

Comment: That's a good idea.  Unfortunately due to our processes in my business unit I have to save over the same file each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I switched the file type from .xls to .xlsm the file size shrunk immediately and stayed small.  From a posting I read that .xls files sometimes have data leaks.  I imagine this is what was contributing to the steadily increasing file size.  I used the .xls and .xlsm files in parallel and measured the file size for 6 days.  The regressions are below:

This is the regression for .xlsm:

[image]

This is the regression for .xls:

[image]

So as you can see, the .xls file is increasing by 760 KB a day with a very high level of significance.

My conclusion is that it is not the code itself, but is based on the type that the file is saved as

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and let me know if it helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Reset_Template()

Dim I As Integer
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastColumn As Long

WS_Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1

For I = 1 To WS_Count
    lngLastRow = 0: lngLastColumn = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        .Range("C67").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        On Error Resume Next
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lngLastColumn = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Rows(lngLastRow + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
        .Columns(lngLastColumn + 1 & ":" & .Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
Next I

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Select

End Sub
```

In addition to some code optimizations the main difference between the above code and yours is that "seemingly" empty rows after the last one are being deleted. The problem I encountered is that: if a row is being used and then the content is cleared out then (sometimes) Excel still "keeps" the empty row in the save file. In the above code I am deleting all such rows and was (in my case) thereby able to drastically reduce some of my older files.

Comment: That makes sense.  I ran it on my currently large file and it didn't make it smaller.  Maybe this won't make an already large file smaller, but will keep a small file from becoming large?  In which case I can create a new template and run this macro daily.

Comment: I just a added the code to remove obsolete columns too. If that doesn't help then you might want to give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527917/how-to-reduce-a-huge-excel-file. To answer your question: the above code may reduce the file size if there is unused space reserved. This should work for small files (to keep them small) and large file (making them smaller) alike. But if that code doesn't help then maybe there are other causes.