# Why is my Excel file 40mb?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, large-files, filesize, vba

I have created an Excel Document that collates Bill of Materials for each job.

I get the data from the Database containing all the BOM's from solidworks.

There are then a series of macros that run to format the table into a readable format, and then add the odd equation here and there.
The original blank file is 85kb, upone completion of macros and resave the file is 38,000kb!
This can be brought down to 138kb by deleting the 'Schedule Sheet' (The one with the pasted data from the table in sheet 1).
I do not understand while it makes the file so large as the data only goes down to row 400 (Roughly).

I have attached a link to the original file pre macro run and the final file at 38,000kb. Please see the modules in these files to understand where i am coming from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnjkdw2eq15mwwc/Schedule%20Document%20original.xlsm?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykktahvdec60s6s/Schedule%20Document.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: on the "Schedule Sheet" press `CTRL + End` and see how many rows and columns Excel thinks your sheet has

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527917/how-to-reduce-a-huge-excel-file

Comment: @RealCheeseLord Post the running is 1045178 :P!, Then the blank one/original is 5089. the reason why the original goes to 5089 is i have an if statement that is returning blank as i do not know how many rows are in each BOM i have gone to 5089 to allow for this. As for the 1045178, i have no idea why it goes this far? Both return to column N, this is expected

Comment: Most of that 38Mb is likely to be the formatting of all those empty cells.

Comment: I second @CLR - try to remove the formatting and report back the file size.

Comment: @CLR  Ah I See, that makes sense as i do make reference to sheets("Sheet1").cells when formating. Is there any way to run formating vba on cells with data in only. Please note: i cannot say the exact range as this changes from job to job and i want this as a generic document that we run the code for each job. i have tried using the shift select in macro?

Comment: @loannis Yes you are correct. it is now an expected 180kb. Please can you help me with a vba code to run on cells with a value in them only. Bear in mind the number of rows will be a variable from sheet to sheet.

Comment: @CLR Please can you highlight the fact that I formatted the sheet based on all cells, so I can mark this as solved? thanks

Comment: @CLR also if you know a way to run VBA formatting on a all cells with data in them, that would be great!

Comment: Try something like: `sheet1.Range("A1:E" & sheet1.Cells(sheet1.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row).format...` - change the E to the last column with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was:
as discussed in the comments, I had a macro running formatting over all cells.