# How to convert excel file into a different format using Python?

Tags: python

I want to reduce excel file size by converting the file into a different format using Python.
So far i have tried json, html and text and all these methods increases the size.

Comment: What Excel file type, XLS or XLSX? If it's XLSX, are you aware that they're compressed?

Comment: A XLSX file is already a zipped XML file - saving further space is not really straightforward.

Comment: xls,xlsx, xlsb...no i am not aware about this

Comment: if you just looking for reducing the size this will help [How to reduce a huge excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527917/how-to-reduce-a-huge-excel-file)

Comment: Thanks but I need to reduce the file size by converting it into a different format through Python

Comment: Probably you can try to make a JPG/PNG image from your table. Less crazy solutions already were mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could pickle the file and compress it with `xz`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
df.to_pickle('filename.pickle', compression='xz')
```

I was able to reduce the file size of a random excel file almost 6 times.